# WebApi HttpDelete woes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I have a controller like this (I will post all the code just so you can see how it is all working).

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles all of the Upload functions, including GetAll, Get and Create.
/// </summary>
[RoutePrefix("Api/Uploads")]
public class UploadsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly UploadService service;

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless constructor in which the upload service is instantiated.
    /// </summary>
    public UploadsController()
    {
        this.service = new UploadService(UnitOfWork);
    }

    // GET api/uploads
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of all the Uploads.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of uploads.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IList<UploadViewModel>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var uploads = await this.service.GetAllAsync();
            var models = uploads.Select(model => new UploadViewModel(model)).ToList();

            return Ok(models);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }

    // GET api/uploads
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an upload by the required parameter; id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The required id paramter of the upload.</param>
    /// <returns>An upload view model.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(UploadViewModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = new UploadViewModel(await this.service.GetAsync(id));

            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }

    // POST api/uploads
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an Upload.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model representing the upload.</param>
    /// <returns>Nothing.</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(UploadBindingViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var upload = new Upload
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name,
            Url = model.Url
        };

        try
        {
            this.service.Create(upload);

            await this.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

        return Ok(upload.Id);
    }

    // DELETE api/uploads
    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an upload.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id of the upload.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.service.RemoveAsync(id);

            await this.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the controller, I have the delete function which currently looks like this:

```
// DELETE api/uploads
/// <summary>
/// Deletes an upload.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id of the upload.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpDelete]
[Route("{id:int}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        await this.service.RemoveAsync(id);

        await this.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

now, if I call this from jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: uploadUrl + "?id=" + self.id()
}).fail(function () {
    toastr.error("Failed to remove the upload from our system.");
});
```

or like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: uploadUrl,
    data: { id: self.id() }
}).fail(function () {
    toastr.error("Failed to remove the upload from our system.");
});
```

I get this error:

> > {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."}

but, if I change my controller method to this:

```
// DELETE api/uploads
/// <summary>
/// Deletes an upload.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id of the upload.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpDelete]
[Route("")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        await this.service.RemoveAsync(id);

        await this.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

and then consume it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: uploadUrl + "?id=" + self.id()
}).fail(function () {
    toastr.error("Failed to remove the upload from our system.");
});
```

it works, but if I change to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: uploadUrl,
    data: { id: self.id() }
}).fail(function () {
    toastr.error("Failed to remove the upload from our system.");
});
```

I get the same error message as before.

I would like to call the web api using the latter statement and keep the **{id:int}** declaration in my controller. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this now.
The **DELETE** HttpMethod does not accept body data, it can only accept query string parameters which is why the appended URL method worked.

Also, the default parameter for a Web API method is already an **int** so the **Route** should be specified as **[Route("")]**. This will mean that the actual path for the call should be **/Api/Uploads** using the **DELETE** HttpMethod.

I hope that has cleared this up for anyone else having the same issue.